# CSS best practice for portlets

Tags: css, standards, jsr168

I need to redone existing project CSSs' - more than 5 files, which describes all our porlets UI to standard CSS file,called portlet-spec-1.0.css

So, I've found one specification for this:
http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/UPC/JSR-168+PLT.C+CSS+Style+Definitions

This spec. is obsolete,dated by 2003.

Is there contemporary version of this standard?

What can you say from your experience?

I think standardization is very good idea, but CSS Style Definitions is too weak to follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the final JSR-168 portlet spec from [here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr168/).

That document has a section on CSS, pretty close to whats in the spec you cited. If you are looking for something newer, you could check in the JSR-286 spec.

I had been previously unaware that there were CSS styles definitions as part of the spec, so apparently it could stand to be better publicized. We've been using ad-hoc definitions of styles in our portlets, and the results have been, predictably, poor.